# numpy copy data while reshaping without intermediate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have two numpy arrays `a` and `b` and I know the following is true about them:

- `a.size == b.size`
- `a.shape != b.shape`
- `b.reshape(a.shape)` and `b.ravel()` will cause a copy/intermediate to be created
- `a.reshape(b.shape)` and `a.ravel()` may cause a copy/intermediate to be created
- `a` and `b` are massive (possibly 4+ GiB)

How can I copy the data from `b` to `a` while also reshaping the data without creating an intermediate?

Following are ways that I have tried but don't work for some reason:

1. `a[:] = b` - `ValueError: could not broadcast input array ...`
2. `np.copyto(a, b)` - `ValueError: could not broadcast input array ...`
3. `a[:] = b.reshape(a.shape)` - creates intermediate
4. `np.copyto(a, b.reshape(a.shape))` - creates intermediate
5. `np.place(a, np.ones(a.shape), b.ravel())` - creates intermediate and allocates another array
6. `np.put(a, np.arange(a.size), b)` - allocates another array, very slow (3.4x slower than #4)
7. `a[:] = b.flat` - `ValueError: could not broadcast input array ...`
8. `a.flat = b.flat` - slow (2.1x slower than #4)
9. `a.flat = b` - slow-ish (1.1x slower than #4)

What I really wish for is the `ndarray.reshape(...)` had an output argument! From my tests of `np.copyto(a, b.reshape(a.shape))` the contiguous copy from the intermediate to `a` takes 1/3 of the time while the reshape takes 2/3 of the time (a non-contiguous copy), which means a copy should be possible using only 2/3 of the time and also not use any extra memory.

Looking into the guts of Numpy, there is a function `PyArray_AssignArray` (used by `PyArray_NewCopy` which is used by `PyArray_NewShape` which is what `reshape` uses internally). However, this function is not documented in the Array API and may not completely handle different shapes as there is another method in a comment that says 'Not yet implemented' called `PyArray_AssignArrayAsFlat`.

Comment: One solution I have found in the case that a.reshape(b.shape) does not create an intermediate: `ax = a.view(); ax.shape = b.shape; np.copyto(ax, b)` (this also checks to make sure `a` can be reshaped without creating an intermediate, raising an `AttributeError` if it can't be reshaped). This runs in 0.58x the time of #4, so even better than the estimated 2/3!

Comment: if `a.reshape(b.shape)` must make a copy, `ax.shape = b.shape` will raise an error. You can only assign a shape to an array if the memory layout can support that shape.

Comment: How much control do you have over the memory layout of b? Your best bet will be to control `b`'s memory layout so you can use `b.ravel` or `b.reshape`.

Comment: @BiRico for your first comment, I know, I did mention the `AttributeError` that is raised in case of unable to be reshaped. My current plan is to rehshape `a` if a copy isn't needed, then if it is, do some other method (like using `a.flat`). For the second comment, I have basically no control. The array is created using `as_strided` and would never be strided in such a way that it could be reshaped in-place.